# Static class method doesn't return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have following code (this is just for demonstration, I won't paste all lines)

```
public static class SearchAndEdit
{
    public static string[] SearchAndDisplay(string code)
    {
        string SQLconnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string[] field;
        field = new string[6];
        if (code == "")
        {
            field[0] = "Nothing to search";
        }
        else
        {
            string SQLSelect = "SELECT user_name, user_surname, user_code, user_group, user_password FROM Users WHERE user_code=@user_code";
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(SQLconnection);
            SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand(SQLSelect, connect);
            search.Parameters.Clear();
            search.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_code", code);
            try
            {                    
                connect.Open();
                SqlDataReader info = search.ExecuteReader();
                if (info.HasRows)
                {
                    field[0] = "Data loaded";
                }

            }
            finally 
            {
                connect.Close();
            }
        }
        return field;
    }
}
```

Then I use it in Code behind file (*aspx.cs).

```
protected void Search_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] information = SearchAndEdit.SearchAndDisplay(searchBox.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < information.Length; i++)
    {
        name.Text += information[i];
    }
}
```

However, the code returns nothing (label **name** is empty), even exception is not thrown. Any idea where is the catch ? Thanks.

Comment: The problem with saying "this is just for demonstration, I won't paste all lines", is that you invariably leave out the part that causes the problem. There's nothing wrong here, so whatever is wrong is in the part you left out.

Comment: You should consider using `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` instead of `== ""`.

Comment: Put a break point in your SearchAndDisplay and step into it.. might tell you whats going on.

Comment: To rephrase / test what @Ernest pointed out: can you reproduce the problem with the exact code you show above?

Comment: I assume you left out the if/while(info.Read()) section too? Your code will always populate your return array if your sql data reader has rows. Therefore you either aren't reading it properly in some way, or your query is actually returning no rows (more likely because of the HasRows if statement).

Comment: Problem solved, I needed change Search_click to Search_Click :D what a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
{
    field[0] = "Empty box";
}
```

you changed the post. you should have this instead

```
string SQLconnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string[] field;
    field = new string[6];
    field[0] = "Nothing to search"; // add here in case string is null
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
    {
        string SQLSelect = "SELECT user_name, user_surname, user_code, user_group, user_password FROM Users WHERE user_code=@user_code";
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(SQLconnection);
        SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand(SQLSelect, connect);
        search.Parameters.Clear();
        search.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_code", code);
        try
        {                    
            connect.Open();
            SqlDataReader info = search.ExecuteReader();
            if (info.HasRows)
            {
                field[0] = "Data loaded";
            }

        }
        catch
        { 
            // error handle here problem with connection
        }
        finally 
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
    return field;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, now that you've shown us more code: if the SQL query returns 0 rows, then the returned array will be empty, as you observe. Therefore, it seems that the values you're passing in for `user_code` aren't in the database -- or perhaps they're of the wrong data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should try stepping through this with a debugger.  There is a case where the `field` array will return an array of six null string elements: if `code` is not an empty string, the `else` clause will execute, and if your SQL query returns no rows, then `field` will never receive any string values.  My guess is that this is what's happening.  If you can't use a debugger for some reason (?), you can always modify your code thusly:

```
if (info.HasRows) {
  field[0] = "Data loaded";
} else {
  field[0] = "No data found";
}
```